# JSPDF autotable - break large table

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

In web app I'm developing i need to create table from data which in some cases can have over 100 columns. Is there a way for pdf autotable to break after certain amount of columns and continue on the next page?

Comment: try  startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20 see if it work